# Embedded form entity is not persisted

Tags: symfony

Symfony 2.6.9

I have `UserProfile` entity with `avatar` property which has `oneToOne` uni-directional relation to `UserAvatar` entity and cascade persistence.

```
BlogBundle\Entity\UserProfile:
    type: entity
    table: user_profiles
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        #...
    oneToOne:
        #...
        avatar:
            targetEntity: UserAvatar
            cascade: ['persist', 'remove']
```

And I created `UserProfile` form type with embedded avatar form field:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            #...
            ->add('avatar', new UserAvatarType, [
                'required' => false,
            ])
            ->add('submit', 'submit', [
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'right'
                ]
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'BlogBundle\Entity\UserProfile',
            'cascade_validation' => true,
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'userProfile';
    }
}
```

And `UserAvatarType`:

```
class UserAvatarType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('file', 'file', [
                'label' => false
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'BlogBundle\Entity\UserAvatar',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'userAvatar';
    }
}
```

`UserProfile` and `UserAvatar` entities already exist when I submit the form, they created automatically while user registration on persistence event. I just edit profile entity.

When I submit form, all the fields inside `UserProfile` are persisted well, but not embedded `avatar` field. Method `setAvatar` inside `UserProfile` is not invoked. Validation on `UserAvatar` is passed well. No errors, `UserAvatar` entity just not persisted.

[Gist.](https://gist.github.com/iHedgehog/a92a64a196b66ce18b23)

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found out where the problem was.

Entity will be not persisted if there is no changed mapped fields. In my case I change just file field which is virtual field and not mapped to DB.

Here is some information about this issue in documentation:

> The `PreUpdate` and `PostUpdate` callbacks are only triggered if there is a change in one of the entity's field that are persisted. This means that, by default, if you modify only the `$file` property, these events will not be triggered, as the property itself is not directly persisted via Doctrine. One solution would be to use an updated field that's persisted to Doctrine, and to modify it manually when changing the file.

And here is how we can solve it. We can create some dummy field which will be changed while `setFile()` invoking:

```
<?php
public function setFile(UploadedFile $file)
{
    $this->file = $file;
    $this->createdAt = new \DateTime;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess, but a very common mistake is made at the controller level. Make sure you have something like :

```
$profile = new UserProfile();
$avatar = new UserAvatar();
$profile->setAvatar($avatar);

$form = $this->createForm(new UserProfileType(), $profile)
```

And then handle your form like you already do.

Hope this helps.

EDIT

Given the intel given in the comments, the problem is fully identified : the User object being lazy loaded, it is not available for Doctrine to persist. What I would do is :

- In your UserController, in the profileEditAction(), when `$user` is defined by a call to `findOneByUsername($username)`, you call instead your own method from the UserRepository (name it whatever you want, let's say findOneByUsernameCustom), that we are going to create.
- Go to your UserRepository and create this custom method. It should look like this :

  ```
  public function findOneByUsernameCustom(){

  $em = $this->getEntityManager();
  $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
  $qb
      ->select('User','firstUserProperty','secondUserProperty')
      ->from('AppBundle\Entity\User','User')
      ->leftJoin('User.firstUserProperty','fistUserProperty')
      ->leftJoin('User.secondUserProperty','secondUserProperty')
      ;
  $q = $qb->getQuery();
  return $q->getResult();}
  ```

Basicaly leftJoin every property of your User, so that when you retrieve your User from Database, it will be properly done.

You can read this excellent [article](http://www.uvd.co.uk/blog/some-doctrine-2-best-practices/) about it for further details.

Comment: `UserProfile` and `UserAvatar` entities are automatically created while user registration. In controller I just check validation and persist/flush `UserProfile` entity. I expect `UserAvatar` to be persisted automatically due to `cascade: ['persist']` option.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but are you sure your $profile has an $avatar ? Maybe dump $profile to see what's what ...

Comment: Why don't you have any controller ? from this repository it's hard to tell anything for sure ...

Comment: Added `UserController` and `User` entity.

Comment: ligne 108 of your controller, could you dump the $user variable and post its content ?

Comment: Alright then, it's because your profile is lazyloaded. There are of lot of questions dealing about such problems

Comment: I changed `$user = $em->getRepository('BlogBundle:User')->findOneByUsername($username);` to 
        `$user = $em->createQuery('SELECT u, p, a FROM BlogBundle:User u JOIN u.profile p JOIN p.avatar a WHERE u.username = :username')
            ->setParameter(':username', $username)
            ->getSingleResult();` and it didn't change anything.

Comment: As far as I understood you meant that I wrote. Now dump shows all entities loaded. But it did not change anything.

Comment: Alright, I read again the original problem, and it involved UserProfile and UserAvatar. We took care of retrieving the User, but we have to do the same for these entities. It's exactly the same thing to do, should be quick to implement.

Comment: I tried to create new project and check relations and form embedding and these worked well. But in my project I just can't understand what's wrong, why only `avatar` is not persisted.

Maybe I will upload my project and you have a glance at it?